# Alamofire stacking responses

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire, alamofire-request

I am using Alamofire to communicating with my API, also I am using RequestInterceptor to catch unauthorized requests or for refreshing the JWT token. When everything is going well, there is no problem at all, but in case of bad response (400,401) Alamofire tries to refresh token and send the request again. There is a strange behavior, since it fails with serialization error:

```
[Request]: PUT https://my.url.com/unregistered?
    [Headers]:
        Content-Type: application/json
    [Body]:
        {"name":"user16","email":"dummy@gmail.com"}
[Response]:
    [Status Code]: 400
    [Headers]:
        Connection: keep-alive
        Content-Length: 51
        Content-Type: application/json
        Date: Sun, 19 Sep 2021 08:13:57 GMT
        Server: nginx
    [Body]:
        {"message": "User with same email already exists"}
        {"message": "User with same email already exists"}
[Network Duration]: 0.21983695030212402s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0001439583720639348s
[Result]: failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}))))))
```

It basically read the same answer two times and tell me that it's not a JSON serializable. I am absolutely sure that server returns only one response like JSON, what is totally strange is fact that Alamofire doing this at any time, once it get back with successfully serialized body and second time it fails on serialization. This is the code I am using:

```
func authorization<T: Decodable>(
        _ url: String,
        method: HTTPMethod = .get,
        parameters: Parameters? = nil,
        decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(),
        headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil,
        interceptor: RequestInterceptor? = nil,
        withInterceptor: Bool = false
    ) -> Future<T, ServerError> {
        return Future({ promise in
            AF.request(
                url,
                method: method,
                parameters: parameters,
                encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                headers: headers,
                interceptor: withInterceptor ? self : nil
            )
            .validate(statusCode: [200, 401])
            .responseDecodable(completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
                print(response.debugDescription)
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    self.saveCookies(cookies: HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies)
                    promise(.success(value))
                case .failure(let error):
                    promise(.failure(self.createError(response: response.response, AFerror: error, AFIerror: nil, data: response.data)))
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Also, I've tried adding multiple status codes to validation, nothing helps at all.

When I've used `.responseString` to get any thoughts I was able to see the response only once, which is strange too.

Comment: If your code retries a request whose response status code was 400 (Bad Request), there's something wrong (most likely not a runtime error, but wrong parameter names, etc.). Only a 401 (Not authorized) should be retried _after_ updating the bearer token or access token.

Comment: You need to provide more info. The log from the PUT request seems to be for registering a new user. This kind of request would not trigger a call of `authorization `.  You call this registration endpoint, when there is no user at all, i.e. no access token and no refresh token. On the other hand, the authorization function will be called, when you try to access protected resources with an already registered user providing an access token, but that access token is expired.

Comment: Well, now the authorization function _could_ start a registration flow, but in your case, it just calls an endpoint, which should be a refresh token endpoint, where you pass the refresh token, and get a new access token (and possibly new refresh token).

Comment: This flow is registering the "unregistered user" - in my app that means user already exists in database as dummy user (without email or password, just id, optional name - also this user has access and refresh token, due to logic of the server). In this case, server get the request, check if all things are good to go -> email address already exists so it get back with 400 -> my app ignore it, tries 4 times with the same result and crashes on serializing (see the question detail with network)

Comment: I need to say that happy day scenario works well, if user fill up the registration for with unique email address server saves him and application get registered state, just if 400 comes back Alamofire sees unserializable JSON or "no response" even if there is a response. Also, I can see the correct response when I tries to get it with .responseString